# tty1 user always show root login

Tags: ubuntu

I have two Ubuntu cloud servers, I found something that does not match with another server, could anyone help me to find what is tty1 and why it's showing root still logged in?

In this server1, tty1 sill logged in not showing but another server2 it show still logged in.

You can see in tty1 login does not show any IP address.

```
root@server1:/home/ubuntu# last -a | grep -i still
ubuntu   pts/2        Sun Dec 25 08:09   still logged in    MYIPADDRESS
reboot   system boot  Wed Nov  9 21:06   still running      5.15.0-52-generic


root@server2:/etc/apt# last -a | grep -i still
ubuntu    pts/0        Sun Dec 25 07:01   still logged in    MYIPADDRESS
root     tty1         Sat Dec 10 18:22   still logged in
reboot   system boot  Sat Dec 10 18:16   still running      5.4.0-135-generic
reboot   system boot  Sun Sep 18 08:06   still running      5.4.0-125-generic
reboot   system boot  Sun Sep 18 05:10   still running      5.4.0-125-generic
reboot   system boot  Sat Sep 17 02:49   still running      5.4.0-125-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec 24 08:44   still running      5.4.0-58-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec 10 21:36   still running      5.4.0-26-generic
```

Comment: In your **Server1** what is the output of `who` and `w` commands? Add the output of these ones to your question. And as far as I know your server1 should  also show something like: `ttyN .... still logged in` (where `ttyN` can be any number from 1 to 7 such as `tty2`). Not sure why that info is not returned by the `last` command.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon

`
root@server2:/home/server2# who
myuser    pts/0        2022-12-25 09:14 (myip)
root@server2:/home/server2#
`

server1
ubuntu@sever1:~$ who
ubuntu   pts/1        2022-12-10 11:03 (myip)

Comment: That's the output of server 2. Add it from server 1 but edit your question to provide that info. Don't show in comments (that's hard to read)

Comment: Btw how are you connecting to Ubuntu cloud servers?  Do you login in your servers directly in the web browser? If so, do you use a terminal or do you login by using a full  desktop environment (a GUI session)?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon

Edit option disabled

here is server 1

ubuntu@server1:~$ w
 09:55:20 up 45 days, 12:49,  4 users,  load average: 0.07, 0.03, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/1    myip      10Dec22  0.00s  0.00s  0.01s sudo mariadb
ubuntu   pts/2    myip   08:09    1:43m  0.05s  0.02s sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
ubuntu@server1:~$ who
ubuntu   pts/1        2022-12-10 11:03 (myip)
ubuntu   pts/2        2022-12-25 08:09 (myip)
ubuntu@server1:~$

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I am login remotely from internet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141526/discussion-between-devaki-and-edgar-magallon).